# Jquery sortable dragging in/between lists with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Basically, I am trying to do a different ajax call for the when there is something dragged into another list or in the same list. Each one should work independently. I am having trouble with multiple ajax calls happening when you move from one list to another. I want an ajax call to happen if you sort in the same list to work independently from when I drag to another list. Should I not be using receive?

```
function sortable(){
var startCont,
    changeCont;
$('#sortable ul').sortable({
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    connectWith: "#sortable ul",

    start: function(event, ui) {
        startCont = $(this).closest('.project').attr('id');
    },
    // update: function(event, ui) {
    //     changeCont = $(this).closest('.project').attr('id');
    //     // console.log(changeCont);
    //     if(startCont === changeCont){
    //         console.log('')
    //     }
    // },
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
        endCont = $(this).closest('.project').attr('id');
        // console.log(startCont + changeCont);
        // console.log(endCont);
        event.preventDefault();
        var token = $('[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
        var project_id;
        var project = {};
        var weight;
        var user_id;
        var route = 'move-person';
        $('.project#' + startCont + ', .project#' + endCont).each(function(){
            project_id = $(this).attr('id');
            project[project_id] = {};

            $(this).find('#sortable li').each(function(){
                user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');;
                weight = $(this).index() + 1;;
                project[project_id][user_id] = weight;
            });
        });

        var data = { projects:project, _token:token }
        // $.ajax({
        //     url: route,
        //     type: 'POST',
        //     data: data,
        //     dataType: 'JSON',
        //     success: function (data) {
        //       console.log(data);
        //     }
        // });
    }

}).disableSelection();
```

}

Comment: I think I see what you want to do. I suspect you'll want to build functions around `sort`, `remove`, and `receive`. Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/s603gmy9/2/

Comment: I think this is the right idea. Do I have to use sort, remove and receive in this instance?

Comment: No, you could bind it to any of the events. They are triggered at different times or by different actions.